# How can I wrap the categoryAxis text on Kendo UI charts

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I realize that using long text names for the categoryAxisValues on kendo ui charts the text will overlap and display on top of each other. I try to check the documentation looking for a property that could fix it but apparently does not exist or I couldn't find it.
Here is a example taken from Telerik page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/column">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/styles/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.1.115/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <div class="demo-section k-content wide">
        <div id="chart" style="background: center no-repeat url('../content/shared/styles/world-map.png');"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function createChart() {
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                title: {
                    text: "Gross domestic product growth /GDP annual %/"
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top"
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [{
                    name: "India",
                    data: [3.907, 7.943, 7.848, 9.284, 9.263, 9.801, 3.890, 8.238, 9.552, 6.855]
                }, {
                    name: "Russian Federation",
                    data: [4.743, 7.295, 7.175, 6.376, 8.153, 8.535, 5.247, -7.832, 4.3, 4.3]
                }, {
                    name: "Germany",
                    data: [0.010, -0.375, 1.161, 0.684, 3.7, 3.269, 1.083, -5.127, 3.690, 2.995]
                },{
                    name: "World",
                    data: [1.988, 2.733, 3.994, 3.464, 4.001, 3.939, 1.333, -2.245, 4.339, 2.727]
                }],
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}%"
                    },
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    axisCrossingValue: 0
                },
                categoryAxis: {
                    categories: ["2sdsdsfs sdf sffd002", "200sdfsf fddf sd fs3", "200sd sfsdf sdf4", "20sdf dfsdfsdfsf05", "20sd sdfsdfs06", "20sd dsfsdf07", "200sdf sdfdfsfsdf8", "2sdf sdfsdf009", "201sd fsdfsfd0", "201s ddfsdfdf1"],
                    line: {
                        visible: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        padding: {top: 135}
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    format: "{0}%",
                    template: "#= series.name #: #= value #"
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(createChart);
        $(document).bind("kendo:skinChange", createChart);
    </script>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried setting the label rotation to "auto": https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels

Comment: The idea is to wrap the labels in multi line text. Rotating also work but does not match the original design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was on the documentation from Telerik. https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/categoryaxis.labels

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
categoryAxis: {
  categories: ["foo bar"],
  labels: {
    visual: function(e) {
      var rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect(e.rect.origin, [e.rect.size.width, 100]);
      var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(rect, {
        orientation: "vertical",
        alignContent: "center"
      });
      var words = e.text.split(" ");
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        layout.append(new kendo.drawing.Text(words[i]));
      }
      layout.reflow();
      return layout;
    }
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [1]
}]
  });
```